# I am trying to deal with automation framework and I am getting a null pointer exception

Tags: selenium

These are the various codes in different packages.

This is my AutoConst Interface:

```
package generic;
public interface AutoConst 
{
    String Gecko_Key="webdriver.gecko.driver";
    String Gecko_Value="./software/geckodriver.exe";
    String Chrome_Key="webdriver.chrome.driver";
    String Chrome_Value="./software/chromedriver.exe";
    String IE_Key="webdriver.ie.driver";
    String IE_value="./software/IEDriverServer.exe";
}
```

This is my BaseTest abstract class:

```
package generic;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public abstract class BaseTest implements AutoConst 
{
    public WebDriver driver;
    public void BrowserOpening(String url)
    {
        System.setProperty(Chrome_Key,Chrome_Value);
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }

public void BrowserClosing()
{
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

This is my BasePage Abstract class:

```
package pom.aut;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
public abstract class BasePage 
{
    public WebDriver driver;
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

//this method is used for verifying the title of the page
public void verifyTitle(String eTitle)
{
    WebDriverWait Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    try
    {
        Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(eTitle));
        Reporter.log("Title is matching");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Reporter.log("title is not matching");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}

//this method is used to verify Element is present or not
public void verifyElementIsPresent(WebElement element)
{
    WebDriverWait Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    try
    {
        Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        Reporter.log("Element is present");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Reporter.log("Element is not present");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
}
```

This is my Pom Class:

```
package pom.aut;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class LoginPage 
{
WebDriver driver;
public LoginPage(WebDriver ldriver)
{
    this.driver=ldriver;
}
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='Email']")
private WebElement emailTB ;

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='Password']")
private WebElement passwordTB;

@FindBy(xpath="//button[contains(text(),'Log')]")
private WebElement loginBTN;

public void LoginAccount(String email,String password)
{
    emailTB.sendKeys(email);
    passwordTB.sendKeys(password);  
    loginBTN.click();
}
}
```

This is my test class:
    package testscript;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import generic.BaseTest;
import pom.aut.LoginPage;

public class Login_tc003 extends BaseTest
{

@Test
public void testValidLoginPage()
{
    Login_tc003 login=new Login_tc003();
    login.BrowserOpening("https://dev.autkit.com/Account/Login");
    LoginPage l=new LoginPage(driver);
    l.LoginAccount("tomharry001@gmail.com", "tomharry1");
}

}
```

Console Error::::::::::::::::

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) 
on port 19807
Only local connections are allowed.
Nov 19, 2018 4:58:23 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the 
remote end``
Nov 19, 2018 4:58:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
FAILED: testValidLoginPage
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pom.aut.LoginPage.LoginAccount(LoginPage.java:25)
at testscript.Login_tc003.testValidLoginPage(Login_tc003.java:27)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native 
Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
Source)
at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at 
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHe 
lper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
at 
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.ja 
va:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0 
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

In you POM class create a constructor.

```
public LoginPage(){
        PageFactory.initelements(driver,this);
```

}

try after this hopefully it will work.

Comment: i had tried doing this but its showing the same error.

Comment: i debugged the code and as i am running its running well till the method is called in pom class" LoginAccount". Then its start searching the elements and i got this null pointer exception error.

Comment: Yes because your elements are not getting initialized when you create an object the constructor of that class gets called and which we trigger page factory method of that class. Can you please show me the code in which you have defined pagefactory in the constructor of LoginPage.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with trying to store a button as a WebElement and then click it.

Either do driver.find....click() directly or use Actions.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(a);
actions.moveToElement(loginBTN);
actions.click();
```

Comment: clicking on button is the secondary action.first action is to search for username element and the xpath everything is correct but still its not able to search for element and showing null pointer exception

Comment: your error is on line 26 of loginPage.Line 26 clicks on the button.  You may have the wrong id for the button(debug this) but you are definitely accesing the button the wrong way AFAIK.   Line 26 should be replaced with my code

Comment: Any reason you are not using a css selector/id? You can easily select the log in button with a css selector of buttons and use Password and Email ids

Comment: Hey Listen when i am writing my TestScript as this then its working fine without extending the BaseTest ::                  @Test
 public void testValidLoginPage()
 {
  String key="webdriver.chrome.driver";
  String value="./software/chromedriver.exe";
  System.setProperty(key, value);
  ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://dev.autkit.com/Account/Login");
  LoginPage lp=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
  lp.EnterEmail("tomharry001@gmail.com");
  lp.EnterPassword("tomharry1");
  lp.ClickLogin();

Comment: but i want to extend the BaseTest in my TestScript ,i think there is some issue in driver initialisation please help me in this so that i can move on

Comment: Hey its working if i am using@Beforemethod in my BaseTest abstract class at Broswer opening method and defining the url over there..........................................public class Login_tc003 extends BaseTest {
 
 @Test
 public void testValidLoginPage()
 {
  LoginPage lp=new LoginPage(driver);
  lp.LoginUser("tomharry001@gmail.com","tomharry1"); 
 }
}

Comment: and if i am removing @before method and defining a parameter of url in base test .........and then in my test script using that browser opening method with url then its showing error ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
 at pom.aut.LoginPage.LoginUser(LoginPage.java:29)

Comment: please help me out